# How to grid 2 column alignment?

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

How to align 2 column levels?

There are two columns of the WooCommerce product thumbnail, but the grid is not leveled.

Could you tell me how to level it?

Best,
Jeil

The grid of two columns is leveled

[image]

Comment: set `min-height` for product grid

Comment: because your image `height` is bigger so its taking room for that try to give one div and under that add all content give `max-height` to that `div` , you will get equal column.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `min-height` to container of each product column. Your images all appear to be the same size, and the reason for the alignment to be off is because the product titles are sometimes two lines and sometimes one line.

Another solution is to make sure there's a `clear: both` on the product container also. The style for a standard WooCommerce store, on mobile devices showing 2 column layouts would be:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .woocommerce ul.products[class*=columns-] li.product,
    .woocommerce-page ul.products[class*=columns-] li.product {
        width: 48%;
        float: left;
        clear: both;
        margin: 0 0 2.992em;
    }

    .woocommerce ul.products[class*=columns-] li.product:nth-child(2n),
    .woocommerce-page ul.products[class*=columns-] li.product:nth-child(2n) {
        float: right;
        clear: none!important;
    }
}
```